# why my code delete all data in firebase when i insert new data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a mvc project. I have done insert data coding. But when i want to add like rating module on existing part. It will delete all the data in firebase.

This is sample code at my controller

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GiveRate(string id)
        {
            client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
            FirebaseResponse response = client.Get("Products/" + id);
            Product data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(response.Body);
            return View(data);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GiveRate(Product product)
        {
            client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
            SetResponse response = client.Set("Products/" + Product.ProdID, product);
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
```

my class code

```
public class Product
    {
        public string ProdID { get; set; }
        public string ProdName { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string rating { get; set; }
     }
```

sample code at view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rating, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rating, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The process is can add rate on the product but after click the button on view will delete all file in firebase. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Set` it replaces all current data at the location with whatever you are passing in.

If you want to add data under an existing location, you either have to call `Set` on a lower location:

```
client.Set("Products/" + Product.ProdID + "/Total", 42);
```

Or alternatively you have to call `Update` instead of `Set`, as shown in the Firesharp documentation on [updating data](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp#update).